# ng command that can be executed on all projects in one go

Tags: angular, angular-cli, typescript-eslint

I have an angular library project with 100+ libraries and want to convert TSLint to ESLint in one go. Is there an ng command that I can use to save time instead of running the below command 100 times?

```
ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:add-eslint-to-project {{YOUR_PROJECT_NAME_GOES_HERE}}
```

I am creating a script in package.json that looks below. which works! but curious if there is any alternate way

```
"convert:eslint" : "ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:add-eslint-to-project project1 && ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:add-eslint-to-project project2 && ng g @angular-eslint/schematics:add-eslint-to-project project3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can always use the following package for your migration from TSLint to ESLint : https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-to-eslint-config

```
 npx tslint-to-eslint-config
```